# Remove duplicates vector of strings, keep first instance. Can't use algorithm

Tags: c++, vector

I have a vector of

**strings.vector input;**

```
bob 
sam
bob 
sammom
aardvark    
money
aardvark    
wanted
```

I need to remove the duplicates but each part of the vector corresponds to the next location. They are pairs.

ex. **bob** corresponds to the its definition, which is **sam**.

I need to keep the first instance, so keep **bob** and **sam**, but remove the second instance of **bob**, so remove **bob** and **sammon**. Only the first instance of the pair need to kept.

It doesn't matter if the **sam** and **sammon** don't match, **all that matters is the first part of the pair.**

The vector is already in alphabetical order. I can't use the algorithm library.

Comment: We need more information here: What language is this? What have you attempted?

Comment: Its in C++, I haven't attempted anything because I have no idea how to go about this.

Comment: Just use the algorithm library. That's what it's for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int stringSize=10, k=2, newlen=0;

    string v[] = {"bob","sam","bob","samelia","bob","sammom","aardvark","money","aardvark","wanted"};

    // erase duplicates
    for (int i=0; i<=stringSize-4; i+=2)
    if (v[i]==v[i+k])
    {
        while (v[i]==v[i+k])
        {
            v[i+k]="";
            v[i+k+1]="";

            k+=2;
        }
        i=k-2;
        k=2;
    }

    // remove blank components
    for (k=0; k<stringSize; k++)
    if (v[k]!="")
    {
        v[newlen]=v[k];
        newlen++;
    }
    stringSize=newlen;

    // show the cleaned vector
    for (int i=0; i<stringSize; i++)
    cout << v[i] << endl;

}
```

Comment: Yes, I used a vector of strings with your example values.

Comment: I just improved the code. Now will work for infinite consecutive pairs :)

Comment: Actually i just stop at the last filled post, which is given by the stringsize. thanks

Comment: What would I do about because the duplicates if its not necessary the second thats a duplicate, what if its the third?

Comment: Works for infinite consecutive pairs. You want it to remove just the second duplicate?

Comment: Fixed "Segmentation fault" for some compilers. Please check it out.

Answer (score 0):

This will remove duplicates even if there is multiple in a row like this

Again note that this is for **pairs**

And only the first instance is kept.
Lets say vector input; has the following

```
bob
son
bob
son2
mark
wife1
mark
wife2
mark
wife3
```

Becomes

```
bob
son
mark
wife
```

This will remove duplicates up to 6 in a row, increase as needed.

I had to remove the blank spaces two times for some reason.

```
    //vector<string> input; is filled in alphabetical order with duplicates
    int size=input.size();

    //transfer to dynamically created array of strings
    string *strarray;
    strarray = new string[size];
    for(int i=0; i<size; i++){
       strarray[i] = input[i];//Copy the vector to the string
    }

    // erase duplicates
    for (int i=0; i<=size-(size/2); i+=2){
        if (strarray[i]==strarray[i+2])
        {
            strarray[i+2].erase(0,strarray[i+2].size());
            strarray[i+3].erase(0,strarray[i+3].size());
        }
        if (strarray[i]==strarray[i+4])
        {
            strarray[i+4].erase(0,strarray[i+4].size());
            strarray[i+5].erase(0,strarray[i+5].size());
        }
        if (strarray[i]==strarray[i+6])
        {
            strarray[i+6].erase(0,strarray[i+6].size());
            strarray[i+7].erase(0,strarray[i+7].size());
        }
        if (strarray[i]==strarray[i+8])
        {
            strarray[i+8].erase(0,strarray[i+8].size());
            strarray[i+9].erase(0,strarray[i+9].size());
        }
        if (strarray[i]==strarray[i+10])
        {
            strarray[i+10].erase(0,strarray[i+10].size());
            strarray[i+11].erase(0,strarray[i+11].size());
        }
    }

    // remove blank components
        for (int i=0; i<size; i++){
        if (strarray[i]=="")        {
            for (int j=i; j<size-1; j++)
                strarray[j]=strarray[j+1];

            size--;
            i--;
        }
        }
```